# In WPF, why doesn't a ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel work on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp-sp3

For performance reasons, I need to use virtualization on a scrolling list box.

My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Fill" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My Code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = _mainViewModel;
}

MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _mainViewModel.FillPeople();
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    public void FillPeople()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var person = new Person { FirstName = "John" };
            People.Add(person);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

My Data Class:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this code on Windows 7 and Windows 10, the list fills out quickly and correctly. When I run it on POSReady 2009 SP3 (a variant of Windows XP) the list box is blank. Using a regular StackPanel fixes it, but I need virtualization. Does anyone know what to do to get this working on XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...that's *not* how you use a `VirtualizingStackPanel`.  You are putting each individual `TextBox` in its own `VirtualizingStackPanel`.  `ListBox` is [virtualizing by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx) though, so you shouldn't need to do anything.

> **MSDN:**
>
> For the ListBox, the default ItemsPanelTemplate specifies the
>   VirtualizingStackPanel. For MenuItem, the default uses WrapPanel. For
>   StatusBar, the default uses DockPanel.

Get rid of those extra panels and see if it starts working on XP again.

Let's pretend that `ListBox` didn't virtualize by default though.  The *correct* way to make it virtualize would be like this (note, that I'm setting the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, not the `ItemTemplate`):

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</LitBox>
```

Comment: Is the example in this article wrong?:

https://dzone.com/articles/virtualization-wpf

Comment: The code looks correct, but if that's what you tried to follow for your XAML, you didn't follow it correctly.

Comment: Take a look at item #1 in the list on that page.  It also mentions that the `ListBox` is a virtualizing control.

Comment: When I set the ItemsPanel and ItemsPanelTemplate I get a XamlParseException:

{"Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel."}

Comment: can you add your XAML that is causing that exception to your question?

Comment: You did get to the crux of it. A VirtualizingStackPanel in the DataTemplate is not the same as a VirtualizingStackPanel in the ItemsPanelTemplate. Why this worked on Win 7 and 10 is mysterious. Also, why in some cases I have to explicitly turn on virtualization is also a mystery. As you note, it should be on by default for a ListBox. Thank you!